# Create offset images in columns

Tags: html, css

I have a two column gallery and want the images in the second column to be offset/have a top margin like this

[Gallery image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKTOf.png)

What is the best way to achieve this? On screens below 1024px it should be one column with no extra top-margin. Can this be done with flexbox?

I have this

```
<div class="flex">
<div>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/01/18/50/drop-5971598_1280.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/01/18/50/drop-5971598_1280.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/01/18 /50/drop-5971598_1280.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/09/21/14/39/surface-455124_1280.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/09/21/14/39/surface-455124_1280.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/01/18/50/drop-5971598_1280.jpg"/>
</div>
```

and

```
.flex{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
margin:-80px
}

.flex > div{
width:50%;
padding:80px
}
```

but the images are not displayed like in the Gallery Image that I linked above. What do I need to adjust?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would code the two columns, with `margin-top` on the right hand column:

```css
.flex {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .flex > div {
      width: 48%;
    }
    .flex .right {
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
    .flex img {
      display: inline-block;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    .flex img + img {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="left">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/01/18/50/drop-5971598_1280.jpg"/>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/01/18/50/drop-5971598_1280.jpg"/>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/01/18/50/drop-5971598_1280.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/01/18/50/drop-5971598_1280.jpg"/>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/01/18/50/drop-5971598_1280.jpg"/>
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/02/01/18/50/drop-5971598_1280.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This has two problems though: Like I mentioned in my post, below 1024px all images should be stacked in one column with no extra margin, and with your code the images are not in the correct order if I set .flex{display:block} for screen sizes below 1024 px